# Invalid column name error while using left join

Tags: sql

I am getting Invalid column name **'PostId'** error while executing the following query

```
 Select a.SuburbDiscussionID,SUM((CASE WHEN b.postcnt IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE b.postcnt END)  + (CASE WHEN c.replycnt IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE c.replycnt END)) AS TotCount
    from SuburbDiscussions a
    left join (SELECT COUNT(*) as postcnt,Posts.DiscussionId FROM Posts
    GROUP BY Posts.DiscussionId) b on a.DiscussionId = b.DiscussionId
    left join (SELECT COUNT(*) as replycnt,PostComments.PostId FROM PostComments
    GROUP BY PostComments.PostId) c on b.PostId = c.PostId
    where a.IsDelete = 0 and a.UserID != 33
    Group by a.SuburbDiscussionID
    ORDER BY TotCount
```

Why **PostId** column not detecting in my query?

Comment: Because you aliased the PostId column as Po in the subquery.

Comment: Please paste the database and ur code in sqlfiddle

Comment: @Vinnie sorry there was slight change in that query. Now edited without alias. But the result is same

Comment: You don't have PostId in subquery b either.

Comment: Yes Vinnie you are right. I changed my query as you said added PostId in b and in group by condition also. Now getting the result. Thanks